# How can i see the errors when trying to create a static function in Oracle? when i run it can't be executed and didn't say any errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a static function in Oracle Live SQL and when i click run, don't let me create the function but also doesn't say any errors, this is very unusual. I will want to know how can i tested to see what are the errors in the function or what is my error

The function basically is for an ADT

***This is my ADT***

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE infectados AS OBJECT(
    cantidad_infectados number,
    probabilidad_fallecidos number,
    STATIC FUNCTION cantidad_fallecidos(cantidad_infectados number,probabilidad_fallecidos number) RETURN number
);
```

***This is my function ***

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY infectados IS STATIC FUNCTION cantidad_fallecidos(cantidad_infectados number,probabilidad_fallecidos number) RETURN number
        BEGIN
            IF (cantidad_infectados >= probabilidad_fallecidos*cantidad_infectados) and (probabilidad_fallecidos > 0) and (probabilidad_fallecidos <= 1) THEN
                RETURN (probabilidad_fallecidos*cantidad_infectados);
            ELSE
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Error: cantidad_infectados es menor a la probabilidad de fallecidos');
            END IF;
        END;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code, yes - it failed:

```
Warning: Type Body created with compilation errors.
```

In order to find out what went wrong, in SQL*Plus you can (immediately after seeing the error) run

```
SQL> show err
Errors for TYPE BODY INFECTADOS:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/5      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of
         the following:
         . @ % ; is authid as cluster order external character
         deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate
         result_cache
         The symbol "is" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.
SQL>
```

If it doesn't work in LiveSQL, you can always query `user_errors`:

```
SQL> select line||'/'||position pos,
  2         text
  3  from user_errors
  4  where name = 'INFECTADOS';

POS TEXT
--- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6/5 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:

       . @ % ; is authid as cluster order external character
       deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate
       result_cache
    The symbol "is" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.

SQL>
```

Problem is that you omit `is` in `function whatever return number IS`; see line #5:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY infectados IS
  2    STATIC FUNCTION cantidad_fallecidos(cantidad_infectados number,
  3                                        probabilidad_fallecidos number)
  4      RETURN number
  5      is
  6      BEGIN
  7        IF (cantidad_infectados >= probabilidad_fallecidos*cantidad_infectados) and
  8           (probabilidad_fallecidos > 0) and (probabilidad_fallecidos <= 1) THEN
  9           RETURN (probabilidad_fallecidos*cantidad_infectados);
 10        ELSE
 11           RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Error: cantidad_infectados es menor ' ||
 12                                          'a la probabilidad de fallecidos');
 13        END IF;
 14      END;
 15  END;
 16  /

Type body created.

SQL>
```